# cannot ssh into Amazon EC2 Instance, first time setting it up

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

Can't SSH into instance, security groups and everything else looks good. Is the not having a key pair the problem?

https://admiral-iad.ec2.amazon.com/instance/62622761750#linker_verify_account=786080552225

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information provided, yes that's the issue.

> When you launch an instance, you should specify the name of the key pair that you plan to use to connect to the instance. If you don't specify the name of an existing key pair when you launch an instance, you won't be able to connect to the instance.

**Reference**

[EC2 Key Pairs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html)